# Q object with string in django

Tags: django, string, filter, django-q

I am filtering participants with a Q object:

```
q_databases.append(Q(sign_in_link="n"))
```

This is converted (with the `query` attribute) in sql with:

```
`participants_participant`.`sign_in_link` = n
```

There is no quote around the string `n` so I get an error when I copy paste the sql script in an sql console.
What is wrong?

Comment: does `sign_in_link="'n'"` work?

Comment: I haven't tried but the query seems to run ok with django. My  guess is that the sql code generated by django is not exactly the one shown with the `query` attribute.